# Add Wifi Printers to React Native

Tags: android, react-native, wifimanager

I am developing a React Native app and as a part of functionality the app needs to scan for printers connected in the same WiFi network as app is connected.As a part of the research i could find only one library [react-native-printer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-printer) but this does not gives full flexibility so i thought of integrating this module as a Native Module(Java and Swift) as a first step i started to look for Android support but could not find any proper documentation or example for the same.Any working example or documentation will be helpful.

Currently i tried [WifiManager API](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-scan) from Android to scan for printers but then once i get scan result how do i configure the printer for the app to print jobs.

Note: i need to identify any generic printers that is connected to the same WiFi network.

Answer (score 0):

What about embed a local web page in a webview and use something like https://printjs.crabbly.com/

```
 <button type="button" onclick="printJS('docs/printjs.pdf')">
    Print PDF
 </button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but it is not only print i need to do but get All printers and display in my app using Print Manager.